# is it possible to extend the block class in model

Tags: magento2, blocks, model, inheritance

Is it possible to extend block class in model? if so, how to do it. please provide me with example. I have inherited model a class from model and i want to inherits class in block using the class i created that inherit the class in model

Answer (score 0):

Php doesnot allow multiple inhritance. There are two ways to do this -

**First**

```
class a { }

class b extends a { }

class c extends b { }
```

**Interfaces** -

```
interface sb { }

class c extends a implements sb { }
```